# Search and open a video with python

Tags: python, youtube

How do I make a python script which searches for a video on YouTube and makes it open the first suggestion?

I have used the `webbrowser module` to make it open a link. I have used the following code to search for the suggestions.

```
song = raw_input("song search")
youtube_search = ("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={}").format(song)
webbrowser.open(youtube_search)
```

I want to know how to make it automatically open the first suggested video.

Comment: If you are using python 3, then `raw_input` doesn't work. Use `input` instead.

Comment: Thank you. That is not actually the issue for me. I actually need to know how to find the link of the first suggested video

Comment: Yes, I know that, but if you use `raw_input` in python3, you will get an error. Unless you are using python2, of course: )